# How do I get a facebook app approved that has a manual login flow?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote a facebook app that works and am now going through the process of making it available to everyone. It has been repeatedly denied by their vetting team for not using Facebook Login and Facebook Connect.

But I want to use a manual process to login, and on their [Facebook Login page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1), they mention that using a manual login process is still an option.

> If for some reason you can't use our JavaScript SDK you can also
>   implement login without it. We've build a separate guide to follow if
>   you need to implement login manually.

Also I noticed that Web is no longer an option for Platform, not sure why or if that's needed.

Is there any step or setting I am missing?